# League\Flysystem\Local\LocalFilesystemAdapter::__construct(): Argument #1 ($location)

Tags: php, laravel

Buenas tardes compañeros.

Estoy intentando guardar una imagen y me tira el siguiente error

```
League\Flysystem\Local\LocalFilesystemAdapter::__construct():  
Argument #1 ($location) must be of type string, null given, called in C:\laragon\www\puntodeventa\vendor\laravel\framework\src\
Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager.php on line 183
```

¿Como lo estoy guardando? Pues hice una función en el Controlador base

**Controller:**

```
?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Image, Config;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function postFileUpload($field, $request, $thumbnails = null)
    {
        $path = date('Y/m/d');
        $original_name = $request->file($field)->getClientOriginalName();
        $final_name = Str::slug($request->file($field)->getClientOriginalName() . '_' . time()) . '.' . trim($request->file($field)->getClientOriginalExtension());
        if ($request->$field->storeAs($path, $final_name, 'uploads')):
            $data = json_encode(['upload' => 'success', 'path' => $path, 'original_name' => $original_name, 'final_name' => $final_name]);
        else:
            $data = ['upload' => 'error'];
        endif;

        if ($thumbnails):
            $file_path = Config::get('filesystems.disks.uploads.root') . '/' . $path . '/' . $final_name;
            foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail):
                $img = Image::make($file_path)->orientate();
                $img->fit($thumbnail[0], $thumbnail[1], function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                });
                $img->save(Config::get('filesystems.disks.uploads.root') . '/' . $path . '/' . $thumbnail[2] . '_' . $final_name, 75);
            endforeach;
        endif;
        return $data;
    }

    public function getFileDelete($disk, $file, $thumbnails = null)
    {
        $end_file = json_decode($file, true);
        $file_path = Config::get('filesystems.disks.' . $disk . '.root') . '/' . $end_file['path'] . '/' . $end_file['final_name'];
        if (file_exists($file_path)):
            unlink($file_path);
            if ($thumbnails):
                foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail):
                    $thumbnail_path = Config::get('filesystems.disks.' . $disk . '.root') . '/' . $end_file['path'] . '/' . $thumbnail . '_' . $end_file['final_name'];
                    if (file_exists($thumbnail_path)):
                        unlink($thumbnail_path);
                    endif;
                endforeach;
            endif;
        endif;
    }
}
```

**ProductController**

```
public function store(StoreProductRequest $request)
{   
    $product = Product::create($request->all()+
        [
            'image' =>  $this->postFileUpload('image', $request, [[256,256,'256x256']]),
        ]);
    return redirect()->route('product.index');
}
```

**filesystems**

```
 'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'uploads' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => config('puntodeventa.server_uploads_paths'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
        'uploads_user' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => config('puntodeventa.server_uploads_user_paths'),
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

    ],
```

**puntodeventa**

```
<?php
return [
'server_uploads_paths' => 'C:\laragon\www\puntodeventa\public\uploads',
'server_uploads_user_paths' => 'C:\laragon\www\puntodeventa\public\uploads_users',
'server_webapp_path' => 'c:/www/www/puntodeventa_pwa/',
]
?>
```

En si el guarda un array en mi campo IMAGE que es tipo text en la BBDD, donde esta la ruta y demás cosas que mas adelante voy a utilizar.

Tengo otro proyecto donde funciona bien, no entiendo porque me da ese error y nunca me había dado ese error en el otro proyecto, gracias de ante mano ante cualquier sugerencia que puedan brindarme

Comment: no veo el codigo de FilesystemManager, el error dice que esta devolviendo un null cuando se espera un string... probaste con validad que resive ese metodo ??? y si lo que esta recibiendo es correcto ... y en consecuencia todo lo que se moviliza en la trazabilidad para llegar a ese metodo?

Comment: Código de FileSystemManager?

Comment: pues claro el error que pegaste de primero marca ese lugar como el punto en que revento el codigo: `FilesystemManager.php on line 183` es en donde uno comiensa a buscar en sentido contrario...

Comment: Pues es un archivo del vendor de laravel, public function __construct(

        string $location,

        VisibilityConverter $visibility = null,

        int $writeFlags = LOCK_EX,

        int $linkHandling = self::DISALLOW_LINKS,

        MimeTypeDetector $mimeTypeDetector = null,

        bool $lazyRootCreation = false,

    )

se que estoy enviando un null, pero no "veo" donde esta el error, ya he probado el metodo y funciona en lo que tiene que hacer.

Comment: tiene que ver el trasado (camino que han tomado los datos hasta llegar a ese ... en algun punto sale de tus metodos para ir a los del framework y por hay debe estar el error/problema)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno despues de horas de investigar y probar aquí y probar allá, les dejo mi solución para los futuros programadores :D

Mi error estaba en el filesystem.php de la carpeta config

No se pq motivo no me estaba tomando el **`config('puntodeventa.server_uploads__paths')`**
Pero logre solucionarlo colocando la ruta en el .env como dejo aca.

```
'uploads' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => env('SERVER_UPLOADS_PATHS'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

También modifique el controlador y me quedo asi:

```
public function store(StoreProductRequest $request)
{  
    $data = $request->all();
    $filename = $this->postFileUpload('image', $request, [[256,256,'256x256']]);
    $data['image'] = $filename;
    Product::create($data);
    return redirect()->route('products.index');
}
```

Para que sirve todo el codigo ese? Para usar en pocas líneas en el controlador la funciona para guardar las imágenes y sus miniaturas

Asi me quedo en el .env

```
SERVER_UPLOADS_PATHS = "C:/laragon/www/puntodeventa/public/uploads"
```

Espero a los futuros programadores les ayude.